# BITS process is getting started automatically

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, services

I have disable BITS ( Background Intelligent Transfer Service ) lots of time.  This process chokes my internet bandwidth. Every time I have to go and stop the service and disable it. But then after few days it again Starts automatically, and its Startup Type changes to *Automatically ( Delayed Start )* .

How to disable this completely. How this startup type is changing automatically?

**OS**: Windows 7

Comment: It could be useful if you provided more information on the context your machines is in. Those settings might for example come in through Group Policies from your domain. It might also be worth asking what BITS is trying to transfer in the background. Also how do you know it is BITS that is eating your bandwidth?

Comment: @TheUser1024 http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1921449   [ sftlist keeps downloading something ( as windows update ) on startup ]  closing BITS service, stops the download.